# How can I choose a specific son from a specific multiple father on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many html elements on the page, and among these elements are several similar codes bearing the same name as the class father and the class name of the son. When I apply something related to jquery to the son who is inside the father, it applies to all children on the page. I want to apply it only to a certain son in The page is under a specific father.

Father's name is `widget` While the son's name is `rgCate` ...
This is the script used :

```js
$(".cate-sections .widget").each(function() {

  var e = $(this),
    dataTypeAtrr = $(".rgCate").data("type"),
    dataNumAtrr = $(".rgCate").data("len"),
    dataLabelAtrr = $(".rgCate").data("label"),
    dataLabelContains = $(".rgCate[data-type=" + dataLabelAtrr + "]"),
    n = Math.floor(Math.random() * dataNumAtrr + 1);


  var sfafsaf = $('.rgCate').parents('.section').siblings("widget");
  console.log(dataLabelContains);

  if (dataLabelAtrr === "recent")

    var o = "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + dataNumAtrr;

  else if (dataLabelAtrr === "random")

    var o = "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&orderby=updated&start-index=" + n + "&max-results=" + dataNumAtrr;

  else var o = "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + dataLabelAtrr + "?alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + dataNumAtrr;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: o,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(e) {
      for (var t = "", l = "", i = 0; i < e.feed.entry.length; i++) {
        for (var r = e.feed.entry[i],
            postAuthor = r.author[0].name.$t,
            uriauthor = r.author[0].uri.$t,
            date = r.published.$t.substring(0, 10),
            n = r.title.$t,
            o = 0; o < r.link.length; o++) {
          if ("replies" == r.link[o].rel && "text/html" == r.link[o].type) {
            r.link[o].title, r.link[o].href
          }
          if ("alternate" == r.link[o].rel) {
            var f = r.link[o].href;
            break
          }
        }
        var p;
        try {
          p = r.media$thumbnail.url, p = p.replace("s72-c", "s1600").replace("default", "hqdefault")
        } catch (n) {
          s = r.content.$t, a = s.indexOf("<img"), b = s.indexOf('data-src="', a), c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5), d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5), p = -1 != a && -1 != b && -1 != c && "" != d ? d : AltImage
        }
        if ("content" in r) var h = r.content.$t;
        else if ("summary" in r) h = r.summary.$t;
        else h = "";
        var u = $("<p>").html(h).text(),
          m = u.substring(0, snippetLength) + "...",
          v = r.category[0].term;

        l += '<div class="Item">',
          l += '<div class="img-content PLHolder">',
          l += '<img data-src="' + p + '" alt="' + n + '"/>',
          l += '<i class="overlay"></i>',
          l += "</div>",
          l += '<div class="details-slider">',
          l += '<a class="Author" href=' + uriauthor + ' target="_blank" rel="nofollow">' + postAuthor + '</a>',
          l += '<a class="Category" href="/search/label/' + v + '">' + v + '</a>',
          l += '<span class="Date">' + date + '</span>',
          l += "</div>",
          l += '<div class="caption">',
          l += '<h2 class="Title"><a href=' + f + '>' + n + '</a></h2>',
          l += '<p class="Snippet">' + m + '</p>',
          l += "</div>",
          l += "</div>"
      }
      t += l,
        $(".cate-sections .widget .rgCate").html(t);
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cate-sections'>
  <div class="widget HTML" data-version="2" id="HTML5">
    <div class="widget-content">
      <i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent">
    </i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget HTML" data-version="2" id="HTML6">
    <div class="widget-content">
      <i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent">
    </i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget HTML" data-version="2" id="HTML7">
    <div class="widget-content">
      <i class="rgCate" data-type="single" data-len="5" data-label="recent">
    </i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to me it sounds like you're looking for the [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method of jQuery.

Namely

```
$(".cate-sections .widget").each(function() {
    var e = $(this)  // e holds reference to this specific .widget now
    var icon = e.find('.rgCate')  // finds a .rgCate, which is a descendant of e instead of globally
    // …
})
```

Another thing I'd do is building `l` as a join over an Array.
That is, instead of

```
l = '<div class="Item">'
l += '<div class="img-content PLHolder">'
// and so on
```

I'd write it as

```
l = [
  '<div class="Item">',
  '<div class="img-content PLHolder">',
  // and so on
].join('')
```

You can add more items before calling `.join('')` with a `.push(additionalElement)`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which is your problem, the most accepted solution is `.find()`. I think you can leverage the use of `:nth-child()` selector if you want to target a specific father and use it again for a specific son.
You can read more here: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Also if you are going to repeat code is a good idea to make a function or a component that contains just an instance of the element so can iterate or insert several times without having to repeat yourself; it will also allow you to dynamically insert different class names while you iterate using the loop iterator itself, that way you can have different class names and will be easier to target afterward.